# AWS Elastic beanstalk Ruby App not loading Production ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Ruby on Rails app on AWS Elastic beanstalk is for loading the staging environment, even though it has been configured as production.

```
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
RAILS_ENV: production
RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION: false
RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS: false
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: test:development
RACK_ENV: production
```

The way i know its loading staging. Is i use the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem to build links in my html.erb files. For instance.

```
<%= link_to(t('pages.sign_in.forgot_pswd'), "#{ENV['EXTERNAL_LINK_HOME']}/forgot_password", class: 'forgot-pass', target: '_blank')%>
```

And this link's base URL is the default variable and not production.

**application.yml**

```
EXTERNAL_LINK_HOME: 'https://staging.blahblah.com'

production:
  EXTERNAL_LINK_HOME: 'https://production.blahblah.com'
```

This just recently happen on my last deploy. There has been no updates to the figaro gem. The only change was upgrading to the latest AWS Elastic beanstalk instance for Ruby 2.2.

```
Ruby 2.2 with Puma version 2.3.3 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.3.1 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma) 2016.09.0
Ruby 2.2.5-p319
RubyGems 2.4.5.1
Puma 2.16.0
nginx 1.10.1
Rails 4.2.4
```

I can SSH into the instance, via `eb ssh` and then `cd /var/app/current` and run `bundle exec rails c`. I get a production rails console no problem. verified by `Rails.env`.

Comment: Can you get to the command line of the server running the app, and check `Rails.env` in the console? Doing this would ensure you're correct about what environment the app is running in, then we can do more targeted debugging.

Comment: i logged in and verified. its indeed production.

Comment: My only guess is that you've not explicitly set the VARs on the new instance for `production`, and the app is falling back on the default `EXTERNAL_LINK_HOME` value.